# Convert GMT Time to AEST(australian timing) in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, date-arithmetic, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a field-**resolved time** .
How do I convert resolved time from **GMT** TO **AEST**(*australian timing*) in  the where condition in SQL?

Comment: What is the datatype of your column.  Is it a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, just a TIMESTAMP or only a DATE?

Comment: If you're dealing with data from multiple timezones, it's usually better to keep everything in the database (and queries) as UTC and only do conversions from/to other timezones up at the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT resolved_time AT TIME ZONE 'Australia/Sydney' AS resolved_time_Aus
FROM yourtable;
```